# Svelte Routing 404 on nested layouts

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm following the guide in SvelteKit docs.

On the nested layouts section I came across an issue and want to know if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a bug.

I have the following layout...(just like in  the docs!)

```
/routes/
  /__layout.svelte
  /index.svelte
  /about.svelte
  /settings/
    /__layout.svelte
    /profile.svelte
    /notifications.svelte
```

In `/routes/__layout.svelte` i have the following code:

```
<nav>
    <a href="./">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/settings/profile">Settings</a>
</nav>

<slot />
```

and in the `/routes/settings/__layout.svelte` i have the following code:

```
<h1>/settings</h1>

<div class="submenu">
    <a href="/settings/profile">Profile</a>
    <a href="/settings/notifications">Notifications</a>
</div>

<slot></slot>
```

every other `*.svelte` file only has an `h1` tag with the page route hardcoded in it like... `<h1>/index</h1>` and so on.

The issue I encountered was that when I click on the `Settings` link it navigates to the appropriate link, in this case `/settings/profile`, but then when I click on the nested link `/settings/notifications` and then click on any other top nav link such as `Home` link, i get a 404 error that says `Not Found: /settings`

If I click on `Home` again, then it shows the `/index` link correctly.

On the url bar it looks like the router only moves up one level... so from `/settings/notifications` it goes to `/settings` which does not exists on the routes directory.

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance for any help/clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need index.svelte file in settings folder, create it and this problem will go away.

```
/routes/
  /__layout.svelte
  /index.svelte
  /about.svelte
  /settings/
    /index.svelte
    /__layout.svelte
    /profile.svelte
    /notifications.svelte
```

Comment: Deployment saver!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and realised the error was in not incluing a backslash at the start of the href in links. eg. from route src/routes/settings/profile, href="about" would go to src/routes/settings/about, instead of src/routes/about. The link should be to href="/about".